# Hibernate JPQL throws Update/delete queries cannot be typed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to delete an entity using HQL and it's failing.

```
    TypedQuery<Seller> query = Seller.entityManager().createQuery(
        "DELETE FROM Seller AS o WHERE o.company=:company AND o.id=:id", Seller.class);
    query.setParameter("company", company);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

The stacktrace I'm getting:

```
Update/delete queries cannot be typed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:33)
    at com.ahp.core.model.Seller.deleteSeller_aroundBody4(Seller.java:111)
    at com.ahp.core.model.Seller.deleteSeller(Seller.java:1)
    at com.ahp.core.processor.SellerProcessor.delete(SellerProcessor.java:175)
    at com.ahp.core.processor.SellerProcessor.consume(SellerProcessor.java:80)
    at com.ahp.core.processor.SellerProcessor.consume(SellerProcessor.java:1)
    at com.ahp.messaging.processor.AbstractRPCConsumer.onMessage(AbstractRPCConsumer.java:32)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:756)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:167)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1241)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

Seller.java was generated by Spring Roo:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Seller {
...
```

Seller_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj:

```
privileged aspect Seller_Roo_Jpa_Entity {

    declare @type: Seller: @Entity;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long Seller.id;

    ...
```

Seller_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:

```
privileged aspect Seller_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord {

    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager Seller.entityManager;

    ...
```

I've tried changing the delete method to look like this so that I don't use TypedQuery at all:

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

...

@Transactional
public static Boolean deleteSeller(Company company,  Long id){
    Query query = Seller.entityManager().createQuery(
            "DELETE FROM Seller AS o WHERE o.company=:company AND o.id=:id");
    query.setParameter("company", company);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
    return result > 0;
}
```

... but this is giving me another exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:33)
    ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

My method is annotated with `@Transactional`, so I don't see how it is not inside a transaction.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019654/hibernate-delete-using-hql) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101895/hibernate-hql-delete-query) seems to be using HQL to do a delete query, so it must be possible, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your DELETE query to:

```
Query query = Seller.entityManager().createQuery(
    "DELETE FROM Seller AS o WHERE o.company=:company AND o.id=:id");
query.setParameter("company", company);
query.setParameter("id", id);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

The DML JPQL queries are not typed, because they only return the affected rows and so they don't need a return type.

Comment: The only interface in EntityManager that allows me to specify any sort of generics is when using TypedQuery<Seller>, don't see Query<Seller> anywhere, unless that Query is not of type javax.persistence.Query?

Comment: You don't need generics for DELETE queries. You need to use the `Query createQuery(String qlString)` method instead. Generics are used when you want to return the generified parameter in your result, which is not the case for DML statements.

Comment: I think what you meant to say is, `Query query = Seller.entityManager().createQuery(
                "DELETE FROM Seller AS o WHERE o.company=:company AND o.id=:id");`, that's how I got it if you read the second part of my question, but that's throwing a `TransactionRequiredException`

Comment: True. I forgot to remove the generic part. You also need to add transactions

Comment: I've changed Transactional from `javax.transaction.transactional` to `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and it's working now. IDE imported the wrong transactional annotation.

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. I corrected from TypedQuery to Query, but my delete has a where "in" condition. If the all records are found then it successfully deletes, else even if one record from the "where in" clause is missing, I get an exception. Is it a must that all records must be present to delete successfully?