# Properly deleting comments on a Post in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jax-rs

I have a front-end application with a JPA/JAX-RS backend, where i want to make a request to delete a comment on a post.

I'm using the repository pattern, where i have made the following method to delete a comment:

```
@Override
public Comment delete(Comment comment)
{
return getEntityManager().createQuery("DELETE Comment c WHERE c.id = :id ", Comment.class)
        .setParameter("id", comment.getId())
        .getSingleResult();
}
```

here i get the error:

```
Update/delete queries cannot be typed JPA
```

Here I'm a bit in doubt of what to do, i could just change the Comment.class and make it a generic query, but inside my facade, which calls the method

I also want to make a conditional check i there was a comment or not

```
 Comment commentToDelete = commentRepository.get(comment);
        if(commentToDelete == null){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(Comment.class, comment);
        }
```

how can i solve this problem in the easiest way, can i return an Object and just cast that, or is there another way to check for the comment and delete it from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you create a **DELETE OR UPDATE** query, you should always use **executeUpdate** method

```
getEntityManager().createQuery("DELETE FROM Comment c WHERE c.id = :id ", Comment.class)
        .setParameter("id", comment.getId())
        .executeUpdate();
```

> The return type of this method is an integer telling you how many rows within your table have been affected

Answer (score 1):

You missed `FROM` in the query.

Change query to this `DELETE FROM Comment c WHERE c.id = :id`  by specifying `FROM`

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019803/6572971)

Comment: It still gives the same error, do i need to make it a generic query?

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the conditional check because as per [getSingleResult()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult--) documentation if there is no result it will throw `NoResultException`, you can just catch that exception and re-throw yours.

So solution would look something like this:

```
try {
    Comment deletedComment = commentRepository.delete(comment);
} catch (NoResultException nre) {
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException(Comment.class, comment)
}
```

Also make sure to add `FROM` to your JPQL query as Alien said.

Edit:
I think you should call `query.executeUpdate()` rather than calling `getSingleResult()`;